# Crossrider : Browser icon not shown in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, crossrider

I'm building a Crossrider extension. I've set up browser button in the background.js file using:

```
appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('lock.png');
appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({resourcePath:'popup.html', 
                               height: 300, width: 400});
```

I've also enabled browser button setting for all browsers: IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Browser icon shows perfectly in Firefox and chrome, but in IE(8,9) the icon doesn't show up.

Once I install the extension using the installer, it shows for first time when I launch Internet Explorer, but subsequently opening IE - there's no browser button shown at all in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are closing and then reopening the browser in rapid succession. In some cases, there can be a slight delay in resetting the button and hence, if you rapidly reopen the browser the button may not have sufficient time to be displayed. Try waiting a few seconds before reopening the browser.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Appreciated, I've to wait for atleast 5-10 seconds before Internet Explorer again so that the browser button shows up in Inter Explorer. 

It would be nice if CrossRider maintains same behavior in Internet Explorer as in Firefox or Chrome- that is button shows up instantly.

Comment: It would be nice indeed and we make every effort to make the behavior as similar as possible, but we can't redefine IE's architecture ;-)